# Solving a system of equations - generalisation

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am trying to formalise a problem that I have. I have two different ideas but I don't know which one of them is the most suitable to solve my problem.

Let's say I have $m$ different sets $X_i$, with $i=1,\dots m$ and $n$ elements. Each element lies in $k$ of these sets. Now I want to find out, for at least one element, in which sets it lays.

I am given $|X_i|$ for all $i=1,\dots, m$  and $|X_i \cap X_j|$ for all $i\not=j$, $i,j=1,\dots, m$.

How big can $m$ and $n$ be at most to be able to find a solution?

My other idea to formalise this problem is representing it using matrices
Let the columns represent the sets, and the lines an element. If the element lies in a set, we put $1$ in the matrix, otherwise $0$.
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1m}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots&a_{2m}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\dots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\dots&a_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}
We are given the following information:

(i) we know that $k$ values per line are $1$ and the other $m-k$ are $0$; so 
 $\sum\limits_{j=1}^m a_{ij}=k$ for all $i=1,\dots, n.$
(ii) the values $x_j=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}$ for all $j$ 
and
(ii) the values $y_{js}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_{ij}\cdot a_{is})$ for all $j=1,\dots m-1$ and $s=(j+1),\cdots m$.

Given this information, we want to find the values for all $a_{i1}, a_{i2}, \dots, a_{im}$ for at least one $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ (all the values of at least one line). Or more precisely, we want to find $t_1,\dots, t_k$ such that $a_{it_1}=a_{it_2}=\dots=a_{it_k}=1$.
(We do not need to know in which line exactly, we are only looking for the right columns to be $1$.)

How big can $n$ and $m$ maximal be to be able to find at all the values in at least one line of the matrix?

I do not know how to include the fact that I do not need to calculate all unknown values of the matrix, but only the entries for one line; and also that the order of the lines is not important.

I calculated the number of equations I have given. This is $n$ equations from (i), $ml$ equations from (ii) and $ml\frac{(ml-1)}{2}$ from (iii). So we have $n+ml\frac{(ml+1)}{2}$ equations. But since we do not need to find all entries, how many unknown variables do I really have?

Could anyone give me a hint of how this can be calculated and if my idea makes sense? I have tried to understand better looking at examples, but I didn't manage to formalise my ideas.

---

Example: let our matrix be
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
We are given 
\begin{align*}
a_{11}+a_{21}=2& &a_{11}*a_{12}&+a_{21}*a_{22}=2\\
a_{12}+a_{22}=2& &a_{11}*a_{13}&+a_{21}*a_{23}=1\\
a_{13}+a_{23}=1& &a_{11}*a_{14}&+a_{21}*a_{24}=1\\
a_{14}+a_{24}=1& &a_{12}*a_{13}&+a_{22}*a_{23}=1\\
&&a_{12}*a_{14}&+a_{22}*a_{24}=1\\
&&a_{13}*a_{14}&+a_{23}*a_{24}=0
\end{align*}
We can solve this easily to get
$$a_{11}=a_{21}=a_{12}=a_{22}=1$$
and 
$$(a_{13}=a_{24}=0\text{ and }a_{14}=a_{23}=1)\text{ or }(a_{13}=a_{24}=1\text{ and }a_{14}=a_{23}=0).$$

(edit) maybe I should specify that it is enough for our purpose to know the structure of a line, at not in which line we find this structure. So with the above example, knowing that we have one line of the form
$$a_{i1}=a_{i2}=a_{i3}=1 \text{ and } a_{i4}=0$$
is good enough. In this example we know moreover that
$$a_{i1}=a_{i2}=a_{i4}=1 \text{ and } a_{i3}=0.$$